# Extract a word from string in a certain position in bash script

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I am writing a custom pre-push hook and want to extract a certain word from a commit message in a certain position.
An example commit messages structure is

- `GRP-0876 CHANGE CORE - (core/components/button) : Some message`
- `GRP-0876 CHANGE SHARED - (shared/components/button) : Some message`
- `GRP-0876 CHANGE BUS - (pages/login) : Some message`

`GRP-0876` - the number here can be of any length.
`CORE` - is one of the main folders in the root. It can be one of the `CORE|SHARED|CSR|ADM|BUS`

I need to extract the changed root folder ( In the below example it's CORE ) and assign it to a variable. I have done a lot of research and tried out a few examples, but none worked for me.

I have tried a `sed` command but the output is the same commit message.

```
echo 'GRP-0888 CHANGE CORE - (core/components/button) : Change button dimensions' | sed -n '/CORE/'
```

Even though my approach is not working, I would like to make it dynamic by extracting at a specified position with the help of regex

**P.S.**

I am writing a bash script for the first time.

**EDITED**

I need to extract that value and assign to a variable

```
app='GRP-0888 CHANGE CORE - (core/components/button) : Change button dimensions' | sed -E 's/.* \w+ ([^[:blank:]]+) .*/\1/'
echo "$app"
```

This prints an empty string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using this `sed` solution on the 3 lines you provided:

```bash
sed -E 's/.* (FIX|FEATURE|CHANGE|HOTFIX) ([^[:blank:]]+) .*/\2/' file

CORE
SHARED
BUS
```

To store this value in a variable:

```bash
app=$(echo 'GRP-0888 CHANGE SHARED - (core/components/button) : Change button dimensions' |
sed -E 's/.* (FIX|FEATURE|CHANGE|HOTFIX) ([^[:blank:]]+) .*/\2/')
```

Alternatively this `awk` should also work:

```bash
awk '$2 ~ /^(FIX|FEATURE|CHANGE|HOTFIX)$/ {print $3}' file
```

Where:

```bash
cat file

GRP-0876 CHANGE CORE - (core/components/button) : Some message
GRP-0876 CHANGE SHARED - (shared/components/button) : Some message
GRP-0876 CHANGE BUS - (pages/login) : Some message
```

Comment: `app='GRP-0888 CHANGE CORE - (core/components/button) : Change button dimensions' | sed -E 's/.* CHANGE ([^[:blank:]]+) .*/\1/'`
And then print it
`echo "$app"`
Prints an empty string.

Comment: Please see the updated version.

Comment: You need to use: `app=$(sed -E 's/.* CHANGE ([^[:blank:]]+) .*/\1/' <<< 'GRP-0888 CHANGE CORE - (core/components/button) : Change button dimensions')`

Comment: Or `app=$(echo 'GRP-0888 CHANGE CORE - (core/components/button) : Change button dimensions' | sed -E 's/.* CHANGE ([^[:blank:]]+) .*/\1/')`

Comment: Worked like a charm.Please edit your answer and include it with
`app=$(echo 'GRP-0888 CHANGE SHARED - (core/components/button) : Change button dimensions' | sed -E 's/.* CHANGE ([^[:blank:]]+) .*/\1/')`.

Comment: One more thing I forgot, `CHANGE` also is a dynamic value and can be `FIX|FEATURE|CHANGE|HOTFIX` . How do I include that part also ?
Repeating replacing it with `.*` doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

Using a `while` loop:

```
while read -r a b c d ; do echo "$c" ; done < msgs.txt
CORE
SHARED
BUS
```

or capture in variable:

```
 app=$(while read -r a b c d ; do echo "$c" ; done <<<"GRP-0888 CHANGE CORE - (core/components/button) : Change button dimensions")
echo "$app"
CORE
```